# How do i add background music on visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I've trying how to add music on an visual basic form. How do I can do that? I've tried
My.Resources.Audio.Play(backgroundmusic) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for a module:

```vb
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" ( _
    ByVal lpstrCommand As String, _
    ByVal lpstrReturnString As Any, _
    ByVal uReturnLength As Long, _
    ByVal hwndCallback As Long) _
    As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetShortPathName Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetShortPathNameA" ( _
    ByVal lpszLongPath As String, _
    ByVal lpszShortPath As String, _
    ByVal lBuffer As Long) _
    As Long
    
Private Const ErrorNone As Long = 0

Private CurrentFile     As String
Private PlayStatus      As Long

Public Sub StartSound(ByVal FileName As String)

    Const StartCommand  As String = "play"

    Dim AudioFileName   As String
    Dim Command         As String
    
    AudioFileName = GetShortPath(FileName)
    Command = StartCommand & " " & AudioFileName
    PlayStatus = mciSendString(Command, 0&, 0, 0)
    
    If PlayStatus = ErrorNone Then
        CurrentFile = AudioFileName
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub StopSound(Optional ByVal FileName As String)

    Const StopCommand   As String = "close"

    Dim AudioFileName   As String
    Dim Command         As String
    
    If FileName = "" Then
        AudioFileName = CurrentFile
    Else
        AudioFileName = GetShortPath(FileName)
    End If
    Command = StopCommand & " " & AudioFileName
    
    PlayStatus = mciSendString(Command, 0&, 0, 0)
    
End Sub

Public Function GetShortPath( _
    ByVal LongPath As String) _
    As String
    
    Dim Length  As Long
    Dim Buffer  As String
    Dim Path    As String
    
    ' Find buffer size.
    Length = GetShortPathName(LongPath, "", 0)
    If Length > 0 Then
        ' Create the buffer.
        Buffer = String(Length, vbNullChar)
        ' Retrieve the short path name.
        Length = GetShortPathName(LongPath, Buffer, Length)
        ' Remove the trailing null character.
        Path = Left(Buffer, Length)
    End If
    
    GetShortPath = Path
    
End Function
```